# Positron and neutron generation from neutron caused by EM radiation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, subatomic

As the title says, is the production of a positron and a neutron from a proton by the help of electromagnetic radiation possible?

Comment: Do you mean by bombarding the proton with a high energy photon (aka gamma ray)? BTW, your reaction isn't balanced: there needs to be an electron neutrino emitted as well (or an antineutrino absorbed), to conserve lepton number. I don't *think* your reaction is possible, but I'm not certain.

Comment: Previously by the same poster: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/134005/is-neutron-decay-a-purely-electromagnetic-phenomena?

Comment: I've expanded my answere to the above-linked question to cover more veins of evidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short-short answer: **"No."**

Your proposal fails to conserve lepton number, fails to account for the observed energy distribution of the products, and is contradicted by direct observation of "inverse beta decay" events in large, low-background detectors (which would see the incident photon flux if such a thing were responsible, and would block any photon of the necessary energy from getting anywhere near the fiducial volume in any case).